# Refreshing Partial view in the view after the Action

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have  file upload control with some other few items to post to server. So, I have a partial view containing the above Items. I have set an Target of Form to an `Iframe` and that's only the thing that preserve the page to again maintain the state but that is not working correctly.

Actually my requirement is to refresh the partial view  so that it gets the latest added item and state of the page should also be maintained `onclick` of Submit button.

In view page:

```
 <form action="/Tab/SaveDocumentFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="frame">
                @{ Html.RenderAction("_MyPartial");}
                <iframe id="frame" name="frame" style=""></iframe>
            </form>
<script>
   RefreshGrid();//The method that gets records from table by ajax and bind the grid.
</script>
```

This is partial view

```
    <input type="text" name="txtDocName" />

    <input type="hidden" id="hdnClientID" name="HdnClient" />

    <input type="file" name="file_Uploader" />


    <div class="footer">
        <div class="footer-heading">Previous documents</div>
        <div class="footer-heading">
            <div id="DocListDiv" style="display: none; margin-top: 2%;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


<input type="submit" id="btnSaveDocument" />
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult SaveDocumentFile(HttpPostedFileBase file_Uploader, FormCollection collection)
        {
After Performing the upload of file 
     return RedirectToAction("_MyPartial", "Tab");
}
```

and this is `_MyPartial`  Method

```
   public ActionResult _MyPartial()
        {

            ViewBag.Type = new SelectList(TypeList, "Id", "Type");
            return PartialView("../Shared/Partial/_MyPartial");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iframe inside form if you can get you partial view inside iframe and then take `<form>` tag inside your partial view and try to post ,I think this will work you just have to pass source of iframe as your partial view.